# how to look for live index.html in ftp

Tags: html, indexing, ftp

We are using FileZilla as out FTP. At the moment, I want to insert a script in the live index.html. Unfortunately, there is more than 1 index.html files on the ftp.

- I was wondering how to pinpoint the exact one?
- Is there a way to trace it back using just the Google Chrome Inspect Element?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

By "live", I presume you mean the one displayed when you visit a particular URL; and by multiple index.html files existing, you presumably mean that there are multiple folders on the FTP server, and you don't know which one maps to the URL in question.

The short answer is no: the mapping from URL to directory structure can be configured however the administrator of the server wants, and is completely invisible to web browsers, so there is no general rule to find out.

Barring luck in finding some clue, you have two ways to attack the problem:

Firstly, you can search for distinctive content: take a copy of all the folders you think might be relevant, then do a "find in files" for some text you know is in the target file but unlikely to be elsewhere. At worst, you might narrow down the list of possibilities before trying the next approach.

Secondly, you can use trial and error: make a list of candidate files, then edit each in turn to add an innocuous but visible piece of text. Then load the target URL and see if it changed; if not, revert the file and try the next.

Comment: Thank you so much! And you are right, I did mean the home page of a particular URL. I guess I will have to do a trial and error. Wish me luck!